# FLEX - Check if parent() exists?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I need to access information in my XML.

The information I need is not stored on every object in my XML, only on the parent. But how can I check if there is a parent or not, so it wont throw an error when selecting the first object in the tree (having no parents)?

This is the code I use now, and it works for everything except for objects with no parents.

```
        public function getParentItem():String{
            var selectedItem:XML = treeView.selectedItem;

            while(selectedItem.@Close == ""){
                selectedItem = selectedItem.parent();
            }

            return selectedItem.@Close;

        }
```

I guess I'll add a if-loop to check if parent exists, but not sure how I'd do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work for you:

```
public function getParentItem():String{
    var selectedItem:XML = treeView.selectedItem;

    while(selectedItem)
    {
        var closeAttribute:String = selectedItem.@Close;

        if(closeAttribute && closeAttribute != "") return closeAttribute;
        else selectedItem = selectedItem.parent();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Basically it should work its way up the XML tree looking for a node which has a none "" value of the "Close" attribute.  It will stop if ever an XML node doesn't have a parent (In which case it will return null).

Or here is the same function done recursively (Why not!) ;)

```
public function getParentItem() : String
{
    return findCloseAttribute(XML(treeView.selectedItem));
}

private function findCloseAttribute(xml:XML) : String
{
    if(xml)
    {
        var closeAttribute:String = xml.@Close;

        if(closeAttribute && closeAttribute != "") return closeAttribute;
        else return findCloseAttribute(xml.parent());
    }
    else
    {
         return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick and good reply. I'll read through it and see what you've done. For now I used a try-catch to handle it.
Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: Try catch blocks are useful if you know an error can happen but you can't really control the source of the error. In this case you can always avoid having a null reference so I strongly suggest you use @Richie_W solution instead of a try catch